# What is the name of monocot seedling sprouted itself

Tags: identification, seedlings

Following monocot (one cotyledon and parallel veins in cot) seedling sprouted itself in between Lemon Seedings. Any idea what it can be ? Don't want to just pull it out. Location is Karachi Pakistan. I have like 20 seedlings growing and this is just one plastic bag in which it sprouted.

**26 September 2021**

[image]

[image]

**8th October 2021**

[image]